# eigenvalues of $EA$ and $A$ , where $E$ is an elementary matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

(i)I need to show whether eigenvalues of $EA$ and $A$ are same or not, I tried like this but not able to conclude, please help.  $\det(EA-\lambda I)=\det (EA-\lambda EE^{-1})=\det(E(A-\lambda E^{-1})) $

Comment: Eigenvalues of $EA$ and $A$ need nowhere be close to each other. You can try this by taking a $2 \times 2$ matrix and applying an elementary operation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general the eigenvalues of $EA$ and $A$  are different :
For example take $$A=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$$
$$E=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$$
The characteristic polynomial of $A$ is $(X-1)^2$ so the only eigenvalue of $A$ is $1$.
On the other hand the characteristic polynomial of $EA$ is $(X-1)X$ so the eigenvalues of $EA$ are $0$ and $1$.